# c# odbcconnection not closing

Tags: c#, odbc, sybase-asa

I've got a problem with the OdbcConnection in c#. I've written a class that wraps my connections and commands into a generic interface. The code looks basically like this (I've left out some unimportant parts)

```
//connection, command, _connectionType and _commandType are class members
private void getConnection(ref String commandText, out DbConnection connection, out DbCommand command, params DbParameter[] parameter)
{
    connection = Activator.CreateInstance(this._connectionType) as DbConnection;
    connection.ConnectionString = this._connectionString;
    connection.Open();
    command = Activator.CreateInstance(this._commandType) as DbCommand;
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = commandText;
}

//Other methods use the DbCommand for SELECTS, UPDATES, etc...

private void disposeConnection()
{
    this._command.Dispose();
    this._connection.Close();
    this._connection.Dispose();

    this._command = null;
    this._connection = null;
}
```

I open a connection, execute my desired command and the call `disposeConnection`. But our Database (SAP Sybase SQL ver.11,16,17) still shows the connection in the "PREFETCH" state...

The `disposeConnection` is called inside a `finally` block after the SQL command is executed.

Why is the connection not closed correctly?

Comment: [Connection pooling](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/html/prjdbc0700/CHDCAECF.htm)?

Comment: Have you tried simpliest example without your wrapper? Just console app with 1. Create connection. 2. Create command. 3. Execute command. 4 Close/dispose everything.

Comment: Make use of `using` block which will take care of closing and disposing the connection for you.

Comment: @stuartd I'll review this with our db admin, thanks.
@Izzy Thats not an option, I'm using the `getConnection` Method in many other methods...

Comment: Connection Pooling is not the reason, I've disabled it in my connection String: `Dsn={0};Uid={1};Pwd={2};Pooling=false;Max Pool Size=1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. I've left the `DbDataReader` open. I had to wrap all the `DbDataReaders` inside a using block. Now my connections are closed when I call `_connection.close()`.

So it doesn't matter if the connection is in the closed state, if any other object is acessing the database, the connection is not realy closed.